# How to set selecting full row with CGridCtrl in MFC?

Tags: mfc, gridcontrol

How to set selecting full row in CGridCtrl?
I already set setting in my code. What setting should be helpful for me?

```
grid.EnableTitleTips(FALSE);
grid.SetEditable(TRUE);
grid.SetVirtualMode(bVirtualMode);
grid.SetListMode(TRUE);
grid.EnableDragAndDrop(FALSE);
grid.EnableSelection(FALSE);
grid.SetFixedRowSelection(FALSE);
grid.SetFixedColumnSelection(TRUE);
grid.SetFrameFocusCell(TRUE);
grid.SetTrackFocusCell(FALSE);
grid.SetRowResize(FALSE);
grid.SetColumnResize(TRUE);
//grid.SetHeaderSort(TRUE);
//grid.ExpandToFit(TRUE);

grid.SetGridBkColor(COLOR_GRIDBACK);
grid.SetBkColor(COLOR_GRIDBACK);
grid.SetTextBkColor(COLOR_GRIDBACK);
grid.SetFixedBkColor(GetSysColor(COLOR_BTNFACE));

//grid.SetFrameFocusCell(TRUE);
grid.SetSingleRowSelection(TRUE);
//grid.SetAutoSizeStyle();
```

Comment: Is your question how to do it by program or that the user only can select a full row?

Comment: AFAIK from the program side SetListMode(TRUE) is sufficient.I just checked it.  What is your problem?

Comment: I want to make that user can select a full row. SetListMode(TRUE) doesn't work for it.

Comment: It works for me. What happens? I have a project with this setting. I click into a cell and the whole row gets selected. The cell itself is focused.

Comment: I found it myself. thx.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer myself. It is influenced by each others.

```
grid.EnableTitleTips(FALSE);
grid.SetEditable(TRUE);
grid.SetVirtualMode(bVirtualMode);
grid.SetListMode(TRUE);
grid.EnableDragAndDrop(FALSE);
//grid.EnableSelection(FALSE);
grid.SetFixedRowSelection(TRUE);
grid.SetFixedColumnSelection(TRUE);
grid.SetFrameFocusCell(FALSE);
grid.SetTrackFocusCell(FALSE);
grid.SetRowResize(FALSE);
grid.SetColumnResize(TRUE);
//grid.SetHeaderSort(TRUE);
//grid.ExpandToFit(TRUE);
```